# Jquery mobile app with cordova in Visual Studio is not responsive

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating an app with jquery mobile and cordova in Microsoft Visual Studio.

I have a page

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <header data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Practice</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="homeLinks" data-filter="true">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>List1</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>List2</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>List3</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>List4</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><h1>List5</h1></a></li>
        </ul>
    </article>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li id="back" class="navigate"><a data-icon="back"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#home" data-icon="home"></a></li>
                <li id="next" class="navigate"><a data-icon="forward"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</div>
```

It works fine when I install it in device, but when I run it in browser, footer is not shown, and other elements are using more width than the browser size. Using css to set width to 100% is not working. But, if do following things, the page appears fine:

1. Resize the Browser
2. Use Browser Inspect Element

If I do both of above thing in any order then it displays fine.

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Also, Another question. I am using geolocation which works fine on browser, but not on Mobile device. Any suggestion or help on that will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What is that `data-role-"content"`?

Comment: Edited that. That is just some typing mistake and not the cause of the problem I am having.

Comment: Ok, finally solved the geolocation problem on device.